# macOS - Swift 4.0 Container View does not show NSView

Tags: swift, macos, view, containers, nsview

I'm writing my first macOS App with Swift 4.0 and 
currently I'm struggling with my Container View.

[I've this layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/37t3u.png)

[Layout while running the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cIut6.png)

The issue is, when I click on one of the TableView Items my Container View does not load the NSView with the "THEMA 1" label in it.
(All TableView Items should load the "THEMA 1" View)

Here is my ViewController code

```
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController {

    //VARS
    var tableViewArray = ["Thema 1", "Thema 2", "Thema 3", "Thema 4", "Thema 5"]
    var containerViewArray: [NSView]!
    var thema1View = Thema1()

    //IBOutlets
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: NSTableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var container: NSView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //setup TableView
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.action = #selector(onItemClicked)
    }

    override var representedObject: Any? {
        didSet {
        // Update the view, if already loaded.
        }
    }

}

//Extensions
extension ViewController: NSTableViewDelegate, NSTableViewDataSource {

    //show what is clicked on tableView
    @objc private func onItemClicked() {
        if (tableView.clickedRow <= tableViewArray.count - 1) && (tableView.clickedRow >= 0)  {
            print("\(tableViewArray[tableView.clickedRow]), clicked")
            removeAllSubView()
            container.addSubview(thema1View, positioned: .above, relativeTo: container)
        }
        else {
            print("There is no content in this cell")
        }

    }

    //removes all SubViews from containerView
    func removeAllSubView() {
        for view in container.subviews{
            view.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }

    //rows in tableViewArray
    func numberOfRows(in tableView: NSTableView) -> Int {
        return tableViewArray.count
    }

    //populate the tableView
    func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, objectValueFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> Any? {
        return tableViewArray[row]
    }

}
```

Thema1 ViewController code

```
import Cocoa

class Thema1: NSView {

    override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        super.draw(dirtyRect)

        // Drawing code here.
    }

}
```

I think the issue is buried in the onItemClicked() method, but as I mentioned I'm quite new to macOS and Swift 4.0.
Therefore I've found quite many results regarding iOS but a few macOS, but nothing hinting to my case.

Thank you for taking your time and best regards,
Danny

Comment: Do you want to replace the view by itself?

Comment: I want to place the Thema1 view in the container view.
In the Future there will be more views, a.e Thema2, Thema3 and so on.
Regarding on which table view item you click, the correlating ThemaX view should be placed in the container view.

Comment: Do you want to use a new instance of `Thema1` or do you want to load the viewcontroller from the storyboard?

Comment: I think for my purpose using a new instance would be better.

Comment: A new `Thema1` doesn't contain a "THEMA 1" label. I'm searching for a tutorial or example.

Comment: Then it should be the view from the storyboard. Basically I‘ve searched tutorials regarding this issue, but the overwhelming amount of sources contained iOs libraries or won‘t do this programmatically. Maybe I‘ll find something smilies where the view in container view is switched by a button or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found sample code [SourceView](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/SourceView/Introduction/Intro.html) but it is rather complicated and in Objective-C. Here's my translation of the relevant part to Swift (I'm not very familiar with Swift).

```
class ViewController: NSViewController, NSTableViewDelegate, NSTableViewDataSource {

    var tableViewArray = ["Thema 1", "Thema 2", "Thema 3", "Thema 4", "Thema 5"]
    var detailViewController: NSViewController?

    @IBOutlet weak var container: NSView!

    @IBAction func tableViewClickAction(_ tableView: NSTableView) {
        if tableView.clickedRow >= 0  {
            print("\(tableViewArray[tableView.clickedRow]), clicked")

            // remove the detail view if there is one
            if let oldViewController = detailViewController {
                oldViewController.view.removeFromSuperview()
                oldViewController.removeFromParentViewController()
                detailViewController = nil
            }

            // determine the identifier of the new detail view, this is the Storyboard ID of the detail scene
            var sceneIdentifier: NSStoryboard.SceneIdentifier?
            switch tableView.clickedRow {
                case 0:
                    sceneIdentifier = NSStoryboard.SceneIdentifier(rawValue: "Thema1")
                case 1:
                    sceneIdentifier = NSStoryboard.SceneIdentifier(rawValue: "Thema2")
                case 2:
                    sceneIdentifier = NSStoryboard.SceneIdentifier(rawValue: "Thema3")
                case 3:
                    sceneIdentifier = NSStoryboard.SceneIdentifier(rawValue: "Thema4")
                case 4:
                    sceneIdentifier = NSStoryboard.SceneIdentifier(rawValue: "Thema5")
                default:
                    sceneIdentifier = nil
            }

            if sceneIdentifier != nil {
                // load the new detail controller and view from the storyboard
                detailViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateController(withIdentifier:sceneIdentifier!) as? NSViewController
                if let newViewController = detailViewController {
                    newViewController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
                    // add controller and view
                    self.addChildViewController(newViewController)
                    container.addSubview(newViewController.view)
                    // add constraints
                    let views = ["targetView": newViewController.view]
                    let horizontalConstraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|[targetView]|",
                                                    options: [], metrics: nil, views: views)
                    let verticalConstraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|[targetView]|",
                                                    options: [], metrics: nil, views: views)
                    NSLayoutConstraint.activate(horizontalConstraints)
                    NSLayoutConstraint.activate(verticalConstraints)
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            print("Clicked outside the cells")
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank your for helping me out with the storyboard idea.
I've made a test dummy, where I had my Main view and made two ViewControllers with labels in it.
All ViewControllers got their Storyboard-IDs.
The Main view had two buttons, both assigned to one of the ViewControllers.
By clicking them, you will load one of the Test ViewControllers.
I came up with this

```
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override var representedObject: Any? {
    didSet {
    // Update the view, if already loaded.
    }
}

func switchViews(viewNumber: Int) {
    let storyboard = NSStoryboard(name: NSStoryboard.Name(rawValue: "Main"), bundle: nil)
    var controller = storyboard.instantiateController(withIdentifier: NSStoryboard.SceneIdentifier(rawValue: "Main"))

    switch viewNumber {
        case 1:
            print("View: 1")
            controller = storyboard.instantiateController(withIdentifier: NSStoryboard.SceneIdentifier(rawValue: "Test1"))
        case 2:
            print("View: 2")
            controller = storyboard.instantiateController(withIdentifier: NSStoryboard.SceneIdentifier(rawValue: "Test2"))
        default:
            print("Default");
    }

    if let window = NSApplication.shared.mainWindow {
        window.contentViewController = controller as? NSViewController
    }
}

@IBAction func buttonAction(_ sender: NSButton) {
    var viewNumber: Int = 0

    switch sender.title {
        case "controller1":
            viewNumber = 1
            print("Button: 1")
        case "controller2":
            viewNumber = 2
            print("Button2: 2")
        default:
            print("Default")
    }

    switchViews(viewNumber: viewNumber)
}
```

}